# Rate of change of rectangle inside triangle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A rectangle is inscribed inside a right angled triangle with hypotenuse 50cm and an angle of 30 degrees.

I have supplied a diagram below.
The vertical line marked h is moving to the right at 3cm per second, such that db/dt = -3. We are asked to find the rate of change of area of the rectangle when the vertical line h is 20cm from the 30 degree angle i.e when y=20.

My method is to use similar triangles to get the area in terms of b. My final answer is +5.72cm^2 per second, but I have no clue if this is right as the answer is not supplied. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the chain rule. We have $\frac{db}{dt}=-3$ We know that $h/y=\tan(30)=1/\sqrt{3}$.
And $y+b=50 \cdot \cos(30)$ Therefore $h=\tan(30) \cdot (50 \cdot \cos(30)-b)=25-b/\sqrt3$. So area is $25b- b^2/\sqrt{3} $.

So by chain rule $dA/dt=(dA/db)(db/dt)=(25-2b/\sqrt{3} )(-3)$.
If $y=25\sqrt{3}-b=20$ so $$b=25\sqrt{3}-20$$
Hence $$\frac{dA}{dt}  _{| \; y=20} =(25 -2(25 \sqrt3 -20)/\sqrt{3} )(-3)=(-3)(-25+40/\sqrt3)=75-40\sqrt{3}$$
or roughly $5.72 cm^2$ per second.

.